# React useEffect() : Most efficient way to compare if two arrays of objects are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useEffect() that should trigger when an array of objects changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setNotesToRender(props.notes)
  }, [props.notes]);
```

The useEffect dependency cannot compare arrays of objects, so the useEffect() in the example above triggers more often than needed. I only wish to trigger the useEffect() when the arrays **differ**.

An example of arrays that should trigger update

```
array1 = [{id:1,title:'one'},{id:2,title:'two'},{id:3,title:'three'}]
array2 = [{id:1,title:'one'},{id:2,title:'two'},{id:3,title:'four'}]
```

Things I have tested so far are:

1. props.notes.length --> works but is not reliable - for obvious reasons :)
2. ...props.notes --> does not work if array is empty - and may cause serious performance issues?

What is the most efficient way to compare two arrays of objects? The arrays may contain over 1000 objects.

Kind regards /K

**UPDATE**
I need to filter out certain "notes" later using a text search, that's why I am using a React state. This is not shown in my example code.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fast-compare

Comment: May be you can stringify the array of objects and add as dependency. Iam not sure whether this is efficient solution.

Comment: JSON.stringify is fast, but will not work if order of keys are different in object. eg {a: 1, b: 2} will NOT equal {b:2, a:1}.

Comment: Starting out with `props.notes` dependency is correct, then inside the effect do you deeper equality check per element in order to invoke `setNotesToRender`. For example, is it a difference an *any* element property, or only specific ones? You'll likely also need to implement the [usePrevious](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) react hook so you can do the deeper value comparison since react uses reference equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the most efficient way

The most efficient way is likely a custom compare for this particular shape of data.  You could use `JSON.stringify` or some other generic comparing function, but it's not likely to be the most efficient for obvious reasons.

So in your example a simple compare function might look like ->

```js
const array1 = [{id:1,title:'one'},{id:2,title:'two'},{id:3,title:'three'}];
const array2 = [{id:1,title:'one'},{id:2,title:'two'},{id:3,title:'four'}];

const arrayIsEqual = (a1, a2) => 
  a1 === a2 ||
  a1.length === a2.length &&
  a1.every((f,i) => 
    f.id === a2[i].id &&
    f.title === a2[i].title
  )
  
  
//tests
const a1clone = [...array1];

//different arrays not equal
console.log(arrayIsEqual(array1, array2)); //false

//different arrays equal
console.log(arrayIsEqual(array1, a1clone)); //true

//different arrays same values, but different order
a1clone.reverse();
console.log(arrayIsEqual(array1, a1clone)); //false

//same arrays, fastest check
console.log(arrayIsEqual(array1, array1)); //true
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer and example! \(^__^)/ I used your approach and it is very efficient! Many thanks!  /K

Answer (score 4):

First of all 1k objects is not a large number of objects, but getting back to the question: the easiest way is to use

```
JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2);
```

But it is not the most efficient, when performance is an issue, the smartest thing I could think of is to use a meta property like `version` and whenever we update the object in any way we increment the version as well.
Then all you have to do is to check two arrays based on id + version mapping.

If the second option is not desired you could use `lodash.deepCompare` or create your own function, takea look at [How to make data input readonly, but showing calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139566/how-to-make-data-input-readonly-but-showing-calendar)
and simply check object by object while iterating.

Comment: `meta property like version and whenever we update the object`,, that's a good way of doing it, it's kind of how databases handle optimistic locking.  And if the data is large it's certainly the most efficient way..

Answer (score 3):

True, `useEffect` cannot compare array of objects so let the `useEffect` hook runs.

But what you can do is to add an `if-statement` whether `JSON.stringified notesToRender and JSON.stringified props.notes` are equal.(Or you can use `lodash/isEqual`) to prevent the set state method running.

However, if you think that is still not an efficient solution, we will have to see why do you need `useEffect` in the first place.

From your code, I think you are setting a `useState` hook based on the incoming props.

Thinking about that again, why would you not consider to directly render the props instead.

From official React doc page : 
https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state

> 1. Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t
>    state.
> 2. Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it probably isn’t
>    state.
> 3. Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your
>    component? If so, it isn’t state.

Comment: Hi Kevin! Thank you for the reply! Yes, in my example code the state is not needed. I forgot to mention that I need to filter out certain "notes" later using a text search, that is the reason for storing them in the state. /K